# There exists on $E\times E$ a structure of complex normed vector space such that the inclusions are $\mathbb{R}$-linear isometries.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $E$ be a real normed vector space. Show that there exists on $E\times E$ a structure of complex normed vector space such that the inclusions $x\mapsto (x,0)$ and $y\mapsto (0,y)$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear isometries.

**My attempt:**  The structure of complex normed vector space in $E\times E$ is defined by operations 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}(x,y)+(z,w)&=&(x+z,y+w)\\ \alpha (x,y)&=&(ax-by,ay+bx) \quad \mathrm{where}\: \alpha=a+ib\in\mathbb{C}.  \end{array}$$
With this operations $E\times E$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.

**The problem is define a norm in this vector space, I have not been able to define a norm in this space, which does not allow me to move forward in order to analyze the  inclusions.**

Comment: Are you sure that your $E \times E$ is a complex vector space. Do you have $c_1c_2 \cdot (x,y) = c_1 \cdot (c_2 \cdot (x,y))$ ? I don't think your construction thus far is quite right. You can make $E \times E$ a complex vector space in much the same way as Gauss made $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @JamesS.Cook You are right, but the way as Gauss made $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ does not work in this context to define a norm in this complex structure.

Comment: @DanielFischer In the case of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ we kanow that $\mathbb{R}$ have two perations, $+$ and $\cdot$, the operation $\cdot$ is important in the case $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$,  but in my case, $E$ have one operation $+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define an $\mathbb{R}$-norm on $E\times E$ by setting

$$\lVert (x,y)\rVert_r = \sqrt{\lVert x\rVert^2 + \lVert y\rVert^2}.$$

This will usually not be a $\mathbb{C}$-norm, however. But we can make one from it by averaging,

$$\lVert (x,y)\rVert_c = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lVert e^{i\varphi}(x,y)\rVert_r\,d\varphi.$$

Comment: I know I've seen specializations which do not require the integration, it must have been for a specific example.

Comment: This form of defining a $\mathbb{C} $-norm is unintuitive,  is there any book where it is proved that this formulation is really a norm?  since I have tried to prove it but since we do not know the form of the norm in $E$ then it is difficult to calculate the integral.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the integral. If you have a concrete normed space given, that is often easy enough, but in the abstract situation, you can only show that the integral has the required properties - and you don't need to do more. First note that $\varphi \mapsto \lVert e^{i\varphi}(x,y)\rVert_r$ is continuous for every fixed $(x,y) \in E\times E$. So the integral makes sense. Clearly $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_c \geqslant 0$ for all $x,y$, and for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ we have $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_c > 0$ since the integrand is strictly positive everywhere.

Comment: The triangle inequality for $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_r$ implies that we have the triangle inequality pointwise for all $\varphi$, so we have the triangle inequality for $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_c$. Finally, write $z = \lvert z\rvert e^{i\psi}$ and use the homogeneity of $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_r$ to get $$\lVert z (x,y)\rVert_c = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lVert \lvert z\rvert e^{i(\psi + \varphi)}(x,y)\rVert_r\,d\varphi = \lvert z\rvert \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \lVert e^{i(\psi + \varphi)}(x,y)\rVert_r\,d\varphi = \lvert z\rvert\, \lVert (x,y)\rVert_c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E \times E = \{ (x,y) \ | \ x,y \in E \}$ as usual and **define**
$$ (a+ib)(x,y) = (ax-by, bx+ay) $$
You show $c_1c_2(x,y) = c_1(c_2(x,y))$ with respect to the complex scalar multiplication given above. Essentially, $(x,y)$ functions as $x+iy$ in this construction, but, if in doubt it is probably best to suffer the $(x,y)$ notation until we really understand more deeply.

The norm can be constructed on this space. But, I leave that to Daniel Fishcher.

Comment: You are replicating $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, but in this case  we kanow that $\mathbb{R}$ have two perations, $+$ and $\cdot$, the operation $\cdot$ is important to show that defined norm is a norm,  but in my case, $E$ have one operation $+$.

Comment: If $E$ is a normed linear space then you are given a real scalar multiplication. The trick is to use the real multiplication to construct the corresponding complex scalar multiplication on $E \times E$. What is harder is to construct the norm. (but, Daniel gave a method)